# How to set up spring context:component-scan to scan "src/main/java" instead of "src/test.java" in unit test env

Tags: xml, spring, unit-testing, maven

I am new to spring and Maven. And recently I build spring MVC project and use maven to manage the project structure and dependencies.

And when I write the unit test, I meet a problem which is I cannot get the beans from "src/main/java", and it seems that the context only load the beans from "src/test/java".

Here is my code.

Unit test: src/test/java/com/web/component/form

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-web-test.xml"})
public class FormTest { 
    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory; // I override this bean by myself
}
```

Config XML file: src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-web-test.xml
Here the following component scan seems only scan the beans defined in src/test/java, not src/main/java.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.web">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

The override BeanFactory class is in src/main/java/com/web/helper/.

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.web.helper.BeanFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 41 more
```

So, I want to ask that is there a way to change the component scan, and make it scan the beans/classes defined in src/main/java instead of src/test/java in the spring maven unit test?

Comment: The `component-scan` mechanism in Spring scans the `classpath` and not necessarily the directories `src/main/java` or `src/test/java`. Can you paste the code for the BeanFactory, have you annotated that BeanFactor with `@Component`?

Comment: Yes, I have put @Component for the BeanFactory, and it looks like the normal java bean. I googled a lot and I found that I can put the "src/main/java" in fornt of the scan path, and it seems to work. But I am not sure this is the correct way of doing it.

`<context:component-scan base-package="/src/main/java/com.crazysoft.web.core.system.crazyvms">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>`

Comment: No absolutely not the correct way to do it as this ties you into putting your source in src/main/java and anyway that is incorrect because your classpath does not start from the root of your maven project! It should be as simple as `<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.to.scan" />`. I still would like to see your implementation of BeanFactory...

Answer (score 1):

To get `BeanFactory` you can implement `BeanFactoryAware`

Comment: That BeanFactory bean is just a example. I need to get the beans defined in src/main/java, not the src/test/java.

Comment: @charles In that case, where is the META-INF/spring directory located in reference to the project root directory?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing your normal application context in the test context.xml? Like this:

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml" />
```

This will probably cause some problems though ([Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) can help to easily replace unwanted beans with mocks).

I don't remember encountering such problems. But [Spring has some limitations regarding wildcards in classpath declarations of resources](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) - maybe wildcards in component scan are limited in a similar way? I usually have some base context that is being importer in the test on, so the component scan is set up there.

Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1):

As somebody else has mentioned you do not include the source folders inside the component scan.

Maven will **automatically** add classes in src/test/java and src/main/java to the classpath. In that order.

So the problem might be due to your BeanFactory implementation. Make sure you BeanFactory implementation has a default constructor and is created successfully. To force ordering you could put a @DependsOn annotation (but I don,t think this is the problem)